# Codeigniter: A Database Error Occurred Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have this new error when i added a new project in htdoc file of xampp and when I run it the is giving me the database error occurred
here is my database file

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',  //ewfcbrhv_user
    'password' => 'sal123',  // aots123!321
    'database' => 'splendrz ',  //ewfcbrhv_aots
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

and it is giving me this error

> Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

**Filename:** E:/xampp/htdocs/aots/application/controllers/Home.php

**Line Number:** 8

kindly help as today is I am first day in the office and i'm stuck here on this error

Comment: your database credential may be not matching. Check you username, password and database

Comment: let me check again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following -

1. Is the password of your database entered in the config correct? ('sal123')?
2. Does the database named - **'splendrz '** exist in your local mysql instance? Also, there seems to be a trailing space in this name. Most likely you need to remove that. ['splendrz'].
3. If none of these work, check your error.log (apache error log) file for more clues.

Comment: yes password is entered correct
and database also exists in mysql database

Comment: With an empty space in the name at the end?

Comment: thankyou the problem was resolved there was a spelling mistake in the database name thankyou sir thanks alot

Comment: Happy to help. Mark the question as answered so that it helps others trying to find a solution to your problem?

Comment: can you help me here? i need your help

Answer (score 0):

Change `'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',`

> to

```
'dbdriver' => 'mysql',
```

> or to

```
'dbdriver' => 'pdo',
```

I think it work.

Comment: check your username  and password of phpmyadmin

Comment: @JawaharSharma thankyou your suggestion worked.. but right now i need a bit help here